# Javascript checkbox toggle div hide show

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I am looking to have a checkbox (Football) that when

Unchecked:

- displays one DIV (FootballChoice) containing a label image for the checkbox that changes with mouseover

Checked:

- hides the DIV (FootballChoice)
- shows a hidden DIV (FootballChecked) that contains an alternate label image
- shows another hidden DIV (FootballTeams).

When unchecked again, this needs to return to it's original state.

Alternatively if anyone knows how to change the label image when checked to the same as the one specified in the mouseover element here, that would also be a usefull altetrnative?

Thank you in advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      
      if($(this).attr("value")=="FootballTeams"){
        $(".FootballTeams").toggle();
        $(".FootballChecked").toggle();
        $(".FootballChoice").toggle();
        
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

```css
.FootballChecked {
  display: none;
}

.FootballChoice {
  display: show;
}

.sport {
  display: none; 
  border: 1px dashed #FF3333; 
  margin: 10px; 
  padding: 10px; 
  background: #003366;
}
```

```html
<input id="Football" type="checkbox" value="FootballTeams">

<div class="FootballChoice">
  <label for="Football" class="FootballChoice">
    <img src="http://web.static.nowtv.com/email-marketing/assets/structure/SPORTSPREF_FOOTBALL_100x130.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://web.static.nowtv.com/email-marketing/assets/structure/SPORTSPREF_FOOTBALL_NAME_100x130.png';"                  onmouseout="this.src='http://web.static.nowtv.com/email-marketing/assets/structure/SPORTSPREF_FOOTBALL_100x130.png';" alt="Football" title="Football">
  </label>
</div>
          
<div class="FootballChecked">
  <label for="Football">
    <img src="http://web.static.nowtv.com/email-marketing/assets/structure/SPORTSPREF_FOOTBALL_NAME_100x130.png" alt="Football" title="Football">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="sport FootballTeams">
  Football Teams here
</div>
```

Comment: I am surprised to see `display: show;`. Is there any property like that to display?

Comment: Try to see here: [http://jsfiddle.net/y0k2z5ya/](http://jsfiddle.net/y0k2z5ya/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *have* to use JavaScript? You could use the CSS [Pseudo-selector `:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) and the [General Siblings Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to display elements based on whether the `checkbox` is `:checked` or not.

E.G:

```css
#football {opacity:0.2;}
.checked {display:none;}
#football:checked ~ .unchecked {display:none;}
#football:checked ~ .checked {display:block;}
label {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding:20px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports)
}
label:hover {
    border-color:red;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats)
}
div {border:1px dotted green;}
```

```html
<input id="football" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<div class="unchecked">
    Unchecked:         
    displays one DIV 
    <div id="FootballChoice">
        (FootballChoice) containing a 
        <label for="football">label image for the checkbox that changes with mouseover</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="checked">
    Checked:
    hides the DIV (FootballChoice)
    shows a hidden DIV 
    <div id="FootballChecked">
        (FootballChecked) that contains an
        <label for="football">alternate label image</label>
    </div>
    shows another hidden DIV .
    <div id="FootballTeams">
        (FootballTeams)
    </div>
    When unchecked again, this needs to return to it's original state.

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zpz3mvuv/

Comment: Thank you so much, this has worked a treat. This is a much simpler solution to get to what I wanted to achieve. Only reason I was trying to use Javascript was when I googled trying to do this, Javascript solutions seemed to be the only thing that was being presented to me.